# How may I transfer a frame animation from one PSD file to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, animate

**How may I transfer a frame animation from one PSD file to another?**

Recently, I created a short frame animation of a logo in Photoshop CC. I would like to integrate this animation into a larger animation, saved in a separate PSD file.

I have tried copying and pasting frames between the files, however, I seem to be unable to resize the frames I have copied so that they fit into the second PSD file in the way I desire.

Many thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably do your Compositing in a Compositing application. If you have a CC Subscription then I'd suggest using Premiere Pro for this step.

If you're working in either an older version of Photoshop or just bought a PS only license then there are alternatives including the now free [DaVinci Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion/features) which is actually more powerful than Premiere.

---

If you're trying to resize a raster animation it could get messy though because they're not vectors. You should be working on a paper space that matches what you want the final output to be.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Paste the frames in the animation from the panel menu.

For more info:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html#copy_frames_with_layer_properties

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe you could just convert your frame animations to video animations (button on top-right of the timeline > "Convert to Video Timeline"), and copy the layers from the short animation to the long one. I just had the same issue and stumbled upon your question while self-answering mine.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Trick,

First, convert your animation in video timeline in photoshop, then group all layer and drag & drop your new file :-D

Comment: that was already said in another answer